# More elegant way to assign optionals to a lazy property

Tags: swift, option-type, lazy-evaluation

Imagine we have a `lazy imageView` and we want to initialize it **only** if there is an image to assign. So we need to check for *the image* value each time:

```
lazy var imageView1 = UIImageView()
lazy var imageView2 = UIImageView()

var image: UIImage?
var someOptional: SomeType?

func addImage1IfNeeded() {
    guard let image = image else { return }
    imageView1.image = image
} 

func addImage2IfNeeded() {
    guard let image = someOptional?.someChildOptional?.image else { return }
    imageView2.image = image
}
```

So if we have lots of `optional`s and `lazy` variables and some **optional chaining** situations, we will have thons of repetitive codes.

What is more elegant way to do this? (Maybe using an operator? an extension on optional?)

**Please note that** This is not for optimization. This example is summarized and the original issue is happening when you want to not adding UI elements if there is no data to present. Also in other situations.

Comment: That seems like premature optimisation. Have you actually benchmarked that creating a `UIImageView` with an empty image takes up significant resources? AFAIK it should not be computationally expensive to do that, so your optimisation seems premature.

Comment: This is not for optimization. Imagine I don't want to add subviews if there is no data to present. Also, UI elements are not simple `imageView`s and pretty expensive. @DávidPásztor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use an operator like this:

```
infix operator ?=>
func ?=>(lhs: Any?, rhs: @autoclosure ()->()) {
    guard lhs != nil else { return }
    rhs()
}
```

#### Usage:

```
image ?=> (imageView1.image = image)
```

I don't know if we can combine the first and last argument since they are alwayse the same.

---

### Update - Option 2

Following @Sweeper's comment:

```
func ?=><T>(lhs: T?, rhs: (T)->()) {
    guard let lhs = lhs else { return }
    rhs(lhs)
}
```

#### Usage:

```
someOptional?.someChildOptional?.image = { imageView2.image = $0 }
```

It's better for long optional changings but yet requires curly braces and  `$` argument (that I forgot it's name)

Answer (score 1):

Using keypaths, I've been able to extract what you are doing into a function:

```
func assignNonNilImage<R, V>(_ root: R, _ keyPath: ReferenceWritableKeyPath<R, V>, _ value: V?) {
    if let nonNilValue = value {
        root[keyPath: keyPath] = nonNilValue
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
class Foo {
    lazy var imageView = UIImageView()
    var image: UIImage?

    func f() {

        // here!
        assignNonNilImage(self, \.imageView.image!, image)
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if it's any "better" though...

You can also write this as a method in your class:

```
func assignNonNilImage<V>(_ keyPath: ReferenceWritableKeyPath<Foo, V>, _ value: V?) {
    if let nonNilValue = value {
        self[keyPath: keyPath] = nonNilValue
    }
}
```

Comment: It's very specific to `UIImage` and `UIImageView`. Is it possible to make it more generic for all kinds of assignments?

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini That was what I was trying to do in the first version of my answer, but failed :-(. To work on `UILabel.text` for example, you'd need to write another method that accepts a `KeyPath<R, UILabel>` and a `String?`, and assigns to the `text` property. I'm still trying to improve though...

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini Aha! I figured it out! See the edit.

Comment: Excellent. But unfortunately, I have realized that calling `\.imageView.image` initializes the `imageView`. (The original issue is to not touching the lazy until it's needed.)

Comment: If I pass `nil`, it works as expected. If I pass a variable that contains `nil`, It's getting initial. Strange!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214413/discussion-between-sweeper-and-mojtaba-hosseini).

Comment: Seems like calling `\.imageView.image!` will fix the issue. I missed `!`